# Material (v5) TextField - inputRef prop not passing ref to input component?

Tags: material-ui

using `"@mui/material": "^5.0.4",`

I've read the migration upgrade guide for [TextField](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#textfield)

Code:

```
it('ref passed to input component', () =>
{
    let myref = React.createRef();

    const wrapper = enzyme.mount(<TextField inputRef={myref}/>);

    chai.expect(myref.current).to.not.be.null;
});
```

Expected test to pass.

Although not what the docs say, I did try `<TextField ref={myref}/>` just to rule it out. (and as expected `myref.current` is still null)

How does one pass ref to TextField's dom component in material ui v5?

Comment: Did you try use ref inside a component (without enzyme) ?

Comment: yes in general refs work. (even with enzyme I can do this : "enzyme.mount(<div ref={myref}/>)". and that works. It is starting to look like a bug with MUI v5.

Comment: Maybe the component havn't the time to mount and add ref before your expect test. Did you try to `expect` inside a small timeout ?

Comment: Appreciate these suggestions. I did try a wrapper.update() in case it was that though.